# OpenCSV + RestTemplate: Array-Types

Tags: java, spring, opencsv

I am trying to use Spring's `RestTemplate` to parse a remote CSV file into a bean. The reason that I would like to use the `RestTemplate` is that it already solves all the low-level stuff of the Http-Connection (mainly Resource management) and I can comfortably set a timeout with it.

So I have written a custom `HttpMessageConverter` that uses OpenCSV to translate a HttpMessage into a CSV bean. The bean is annotated with the according CsvToBean annotation of OpenCSV. The issue is, however, that RestTemplate delivers you exactly what you specify in the as the Class-Parameter.

```
restTemplate.exchange("www.exmample.com", HttpMethod.GET, null, MyDTO.class)
```

Above code will always return exactly ONE MyDTO. If you want to have a List of MyDTO instead, then with RestTemplate you have to specify this instead:

```
restTemplate.exchange("www.exmample.com", HttpMethod.GET, null, MyDTO[].class)
```

OpenCSV, however, works differently.

```
final CsvToBeanBuilder<MyDTO> beanBuilder = new CsvToBeanBuilder<>(new InputStreamReader(httpInputMessage.getBody()));
beanBuilder.withType(MyDTO.class); // not sure of this is needed
beanBuilder.build().parse(); // returns List<MyDTO>
```

So OpenCSV takes the singular, non-array version of the DTO and its parse-it-all function returns a list of what was given. The issue with that is that I am using OpenCSV inside my custom HttpMessageConverter. So I am forced to work with the Class type that I am getting from the RestTemplate:

```
// Inside of my class that extends HttpMessageConverter<T>

@Override
public T read(final Class<? extends T> aClass, final HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage) 
    throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {

  final CsvToBeanBuilder<T> beanBuilder = new CsvToBeanBuilder<>(new InputStreamReader(httpInputMessage.getBody()));
  beanBuilder.withType(aClass); // This throws an exception if aClass is of MyDTO[].class. 
                                // The exception states that there is no way to init the class.
  // This returns a List<Class<T>> which is already wrong. This findFirst() workaround could work but it fails earlier
  return beanBuilder.build().parse().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

The only solution that I can think of is to hardcode the classes that I actually want into my custom HttpMessageConverter. I would like to avoid that because then this message converter has no reusability for the rest of the project. 
Are there any other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use ParameterizedTypeReference. That way you can parse it as ParameterizedTypeReference>.